# How can I use Visual studio Code's ros extension to display urdf models?

Tags: visual-studio-code, urdf

[file:///D:/urdfpreviewer3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVol1.png)I want to use the VScode extension Develop Robot Operating System (ROS) with Visual studio Code to display urdf models. Currently, when I open Visual studio Code with catkin_ws and use Ctrl + Shift + P to open the vscode command palette and do ROS: Preview URDF, I get a black screen with no error message as shown in the following image.  Please let me know the solution.

I have re-installed the extension　ros for Visual studio Code many times.

Answer (score 1):

The VScode extension use "robotwebtools.org" for running the URDF, and this domain is down at this moment.

You can go to the **"Ros" extension** and click on **"Switch to pre-release Version"** and after a vs code reboot, you can enjoy the "Ros: preview URDF".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the maintainer, RobotWebTools.org is down which the vscode ROS extension depends on per the recommendation of the docs.

The issue can be tracked at https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/issues/908.